# Attaching the same onClick event to Google Map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, prototype

The code below is from a Google Maps tutorial, with some changes for something I'm working on (so some parts won't make sense right now).

It has an onClick event for the map, so if you click a random place on the map, or if you click a specific "place" it will show directions.

However, I want to attach the same onClick event to the markers. This code uses "prototype" which I'm not overly familiar with.

Really, at this point, all I need to know is how to call the ClickEventHandler function when a marker is clicked. The function is called properly for "place" clicks, and random map clicks, but not for clicks on map markers.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {

        var origin = {lat: -33.871, lng: 151.197};


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: origin,
          zoom: 12
        });

        var clickHandler = new ClickEventHandler(map, origin);

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('https://www.tivahost.com/test/maps/NLPOI.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);


              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};


            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var icons = {
              restaurant: {
                icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
              },
              bar: {
                icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
              },
              info: {
                icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
              }
            };

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icons[type].icon,

                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);

              });

            });
          });
        }



      /**
       * @constructor
       */
      var ClickEventHandler = function(map, origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.map = map;
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
//        this.placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        this.infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        this.infowindow.setContent(this.infowindowContent);

        // Listen for clicks on the map.
        this.map.addListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
      };

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.handleClick = function(event) {
        console.log('You clicked on: ' + event.latLng);
        // If the event has a placeId, use it.
        if (event.placeId) {
          console.log('You clicked on place:' + event.placeId);

          // Calling e.stop() on the event prevents the default info window from
          // showing.
          // If you call stop here when there is no placeId you will prevent some
          // other map click event handlers from receiving the event.
          event.stop();
          this.calculateAndDisplayRoutePlace(event.placeId);
//          this.getPlaceInformation(event.placeId);
        }
        else {
          event.stop();
          this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(event.latLng);          
        }
      };

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.calculateAndDisplayRoutePlace = function(placeId) {
        var me = this;
        this.directionsService.route({
          origin: this.origin,
          destination: {placeId: placeId},
          travelMode: 'WALKING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      };

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.calculateAndDisplayRoute = function(latLng) {
        var me = this;
        this.directionsService.route({
          origin: this.origin,
          destination: latLng,
          travelMode: 'WALKING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      };      

      ClickEventHandler.prototype.getPlaceInformation = function(placeId) {
        var me = this;
        this.placesService.getDetails({placeId: placeId}, function(place, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.infowindow.close();
            me.infowindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            me.infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
            me.infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
            me.infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
            me.infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent =
                place.formatted_address;
            me.infowindow.open(me.map);
          }
        });
      };



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAeuBDdFj7e9OS-gIXIKD51gVd3Ko4hod4&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote without commenting why. If it's for not showing what I've tried already, people need to understand that is not always possible or practical. I have tried quite a few things already. If I were to include them all here it wouldn't provide any value. In addition to that, when someone starts working on an issue posting here is not something that comes to mind until they run into a problem. So I didn't keep a record of the things I have tried, because I didn't anticipate having to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a "proper" answer but here's one way of binding the click event to a marker in similar situation, if you pass in the argument of `place`, when you create a marker (ie. through search callback):

```
function createPlaceMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
        event.placeId = place.place_id;
        clickHandler.handleClick(event);
    });
}
```

If you don't have the `place` of the marker it doesn't make sense to display that info window anyway.